# Get beginning of the month Elixir

Tags: elixir

cant able to get the beginning of month from Ecto.Date

```
Ecto.Date.utc => #Ecto.Date<2017-09-15>
Ecto.Date.utc.beginning_of_month   requires => 2017-09-01
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the value of `day` to `1` using the Map update syntax:

```
iex(1)> today = Ecto.Date.utc
#Ecto.Date<2017-09-15>
iex(2)> %{today | day: 1}
#Ecto.Date<2017-09-01>
```

`Ecto.Date` is deprecated in the latest Ecto, so if you migrate to Elixir core's new `Date` struct, the same technique will work for it as well:

```
iex(3)> today = Date.utc_today
~D[2017-09-15]
iex(4)> %{today | day: 1}
~D[2017-09-01]
```

Answer (score 1):

Elixir now has some built-in functions for this.

```
iex> Date.beginning_of_month(~D[2000-01-31])
~D[2000-01-01]
iex> Date.end_of_month(~D[2000-01-01])
~D[2000-01-31]
```

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#beginning_of_month/1